# Entry point and sections?

Tags: entry-point

I have this file http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~caspl132/wiki.files/lab7/a.out , 
and I'm not really sure where is the entry point or how many sections are there.

Could someone **explain**  and **detail** please? I'm not 100% sure on the definition of an entry point, so explaining rather then answering the question would be much better.

Thanks!

Comment: Analogy - int main in C code is the entry point for the code.  You can create a .o file from code with no main.  Then those functions in the code that have external scope ( can be seen by the linker) are entry points as well.  The nm command will show entry points in these files.

Comment: The nm shows the entry points? But man nm tells me it returns the symbols..

Comment: In a .o file the functions may be entry points, if they can be linked.  A symbol is an object - for example: a function, a data object.  What the output of nm looks may vary by system architecture. You man page for nm will tell you what you are looking at.